# Git svn changes branch url to trunk

Tags: git

I have been using git svn with worktrees for a few months now without issue. Recently, I noticed that the URL for one of my worktree branches somehow got changed to the trunk. There are some documented techniques to fix the URL, but I'm not sure they apply when using worktrees.

The following seems to work on dry-run but hangs without it.

```
git svn dcommit --commit-url svn+ssh://... 
... 
14:14:23.360913 git.c:439 trace: built-in: git config --get i18n.commitencoding
```

I can run the above git config myself and it does not hang. I realize I am abusing the commit-url feature, but from the trace output, that does not appear to be the cause of the problem. Any suggestions, other than the obvious blow away the branch and start over?

```
git --version
git version 2.26.0.windows.1
```

---

I'm still seeing this behavior as of version 2.30.0.windows.2. I was able to use merge this time instead of rebase. It didn't change the URL when it hit merge conflicts. Also, even though I committed with non-linear history, it doesn't seem to have caused a problem when pushed to svn.

Comment: After going through this several times, I've discovered that the URL is getting changed when I hit a merge conflict. After resolving the conflicts, HEAD is restored, but the URL does not get changed back.

Comment: As a workaround, you can do a soft reset after the rebase and then commit. For some reason this left some files out, but it's probably an unrelated issue.

Comment: It appears the URL can get changed even when there isn't a merge conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue I was having was due to trying to push commits to svn after rewriting history with rebase. Since svn does not support rewriting history, this obviously must fail. Assuming I'm correct about this, it would be nice if there were a meaningful error message rather than altering the URL.

---

Update

I've learned that git merge doesn't cause this problem. More importantly, I've learned the hard way that git svn doesn't seem to respect svn mergeinfo, and this really breaks things for coworkers using svn. So the solution seems to be to use svn merge.